# (Visual Studio/C#) Add file to Intellisense, but don't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I'm writing a C# library at work for internal use. The use cases are pretty specific, so I want people who use it to have a couple samples `Program.cs` to get them started.

The problem I have is that if I do nothing, I get a bunch of errors "Only one compilation unit can have top level statements", which is expected because of my samples, so I add a:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Samples\Program-*.cs"/>
    <Content Include="Samples\Program-*.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The first line flat-out removes the files from solution, where as the second adds them back as content files.

At this point everything works, but I am very annoyed with this solution because I can't use auto-completion or syntax highlighting while writing those sample programs, which makes the process unpleasant. Let me be clear, it's not then end of the world, but would it be possible to keep all of the good stuff Visual Studio provides, without compiling?

(I looked at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950547/add-file-to-project-for-intellisense-but-do-not-compile) and it's not quite what I need, this question if I understand the accepted answer properly works for projects, I want it to work for specific files.)

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest using an unit-test project for samples instead, that can be a simple way to demonstrate correct usage. Or make your main method a simple "sample browser" that lets the user select what sample to run. I would be careful messing about to much with project files, since even if you can get it to work, will anyone else understand what it does?

Comment: I'm really not a fan of including files like this in a library. This is what docs and sample reference projects should be used for.

Comment: @JonasH Actually, my approach is very similar to what you suggest, in my unit-test project I have the `Samples` folder,  each sample I can paste in the unit-test before compile, so I know the sample program is well formed. This part works (it builds without error), it's just that I have the issue with "only one top-level compilation unit" from intellisense, I don't know how to tell it "don't worry only one is gonna be there, but I still want your help with all of them". I know there are plenty of ways around this issue (maybe better ways, like @DavidG suggests), but at this point I wanna know

Comment: There are some plugins that allow you to run unit tests directly from Visual Studio. Copy/pasting code seem unnecessary. Just press the button next to the test method and select "Run" or "Debug".

Comment: @Hadron There may be no perfect method for your usage. You can take a look at my answer. It can avoid encountering error when writing(even multi entrypoints.). Because of the tightly integrated of VS intellisense and Roslyn, your expected usage may be hard/impossible to achieve. I have the same notion as JonasH, I also suggest using unit test projects for samples instead. :)

Comment: Yeah I guess I wasn't in the proper mindset for C#/Visual Studio, I usually use GNU Make and VS Code where this approach has been working fine for years and I think I wanted to emulate that behavior in Visual Studio, but I understand it's just not how it works. In the end I have done pretty much what all of you suggest, and to include multiple "main/top-level" samples I had to create sample projects like @DavidG suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your situation:

[image]

This situation comes from the feature you are using:

[Top level statement](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements.md#only-one-top-level-file)

This is a new feature start from C# 9.

Why your solution makes the intellisense of VS disappear is because of two reasons:

**1, First, the .cs file was not match the regularity of C# project.(In your situation, two .cs file used top level statement, which is incorrect usage.)**

**2, Second, in this situation, by setting the file as `<Content>`, you're essentially telling Visual Studio that this file is just content (like a text or data file) and not something it should provide C# Intellisense for.**

I suggest you to use common program's entry point instead of top level statement, so that you will be able to use intellisense and no error output while you writing code.

For example:

***Program.cs:***

```
namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Put the code here.
        }
    }
}
```

***Samples/Program1.cs:***

```
namespace ConsoleApp11.Samples 
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Put the code here.
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that in this situation, the usage still not correct, because there are multiple entry point, we just not encounter issue when writing.

You still need to exclude the file in .csproj file like this if you want to run the app:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Samples\Program1.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Samples\Program1.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Or use [C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) such as:

```
#if NEVER_COMPILE
namespace ConsoleApp11.Samples
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Put the code here.
            Console.WriteLine("This is program1.");
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

In Visual Studio, Intellisense and the compiler are tightly integrated. The [Roslyn compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), which is the .NET compiler platform, is responsible for both compiling code and providing code analysis services that power features like Intellisense. many intellisense issue of VS will also be report here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Since the Intellisense process relies on the list of files that are marked for compilation, you must make a choice. If you mark the file as compile by some means, you will encounter the error output. If you exclude the file from compile, you will lose mostly intellisense.

By the way, you can also follow JonasH's suggestion, use unit test project in this situation. That will be more suitable.